# Replication(master/slave) in Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, master-slave

I trying to upgrade rails 5 from rails 4.

I use octopus gem to make master-slave DB in rails 4.

I guess Octopus may not upgrade soon in Rails5 & Ruby 2.3.1. 
So, I find other master-slave gems. However I don't find.

How can I make master-slave DB in rails 5?

Comment: Why do you need replication during the upgrade? Backups should be sufficient, so long as you correctly test your upgrade path, and you have a rollback plan in case of failure (i.e. restore from backup).